# Does referencing a file twice double the load time/webpage size?

Tags: html, css

This might be a dumb question but if I have a webpage with a video file that is loaded in two different locations, does that mean the webpage size/load time is doubled, or because it is referencing the same file does the video only have to load once?

To be clear, the video shows up in one place on desktop (desktop defined using @media min-width CSS) and in a different place on mobile. Instead of repositioning the same video using CSS I called it a second time in the html. Is this a bad habit?

Comment: Not at all since today's browsers are very smart they use caching technique to handle these types of requests. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751115/8677188) may help.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't load the CSS or script(s) twice. But it's bad practice to refer same files (CSS, JS files) twice.
For exact information, what resources are loaded and how much time it took you can always refer to network tab of browser console. Below is reference of same for you.

[image: It show the CSS downloaded only once, though I refereed same css twice on HTML.]

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
It's too much load. I have solution that in desktop view. please mobile view video applied **display:none** css property and in mobile view. please desktop view video applied **display:none** . please use the code below.

Example:

```
html :
<div class="demo-video">
<video src="video/demo.mp4" class="desktop-view"></video>   
<video src="video/demo.mp4" class="mobile-view"></video>   
</div>

css:   
   .mobile-view { display:none; }
   @media screen only (max-width:767px) { .desktop-view { display:none; }
   .mobile-view { display:block; }   }
```